# How to synchronize two topics without message loss?

Tags: ros, timesynchronizer, message-filters, approximatetime

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

#### Context

[image: Synchronizer]

In order to assess the performance of AMCL, I am trying to synchronize two topics :

- The estimated pose from AMCL output
- The scan from the laser range

`/scan` topic is published at 25Hz

`/localizer_pose` topic is published at a variable frequency depending on the robot's movement (Max is about 3Hz).

The topics are not synchronized, as AMCL introduce a variable delay.
As the `/localizer_pose` topic is published at a low frequency, I do not want to lose any pose message, or at worse very few.

I use a bagfile to replay the scenario to be able to compare different solutions.
I also added a simple subscriber on the `/localizer_pose` topic, to get the total amount of pose received.

ROS Indigo, with Ubuntu Server 14.04.

#### Test1: Message filters, exact time

First test, add a TimeSynchronizer to see if an exact timestamp match could do the trick.

```
//Declarations
message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::LaserScan>* m_scanSubscriber;
message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::PoseWithCovarianceStamped>* m_localizerPoseMsgFilterSubscriber;
message_filters::TimeSynchronizer<geometry_msgs::PoseWithCovarianceStamped, sensor_msgs::LaserScan>* m_scanLocalizerPoseSynchronizer;

//Callbacks
void MyClass::localizerPoseCallback(const geometry_msgs::PoseWithCovarianceStampedConstPtr& pose)
{
    m_localizerPoseCount++;
}

void MyClass::localizerPoseWithScanCallback(const geometry_msgs::PoseWithCovarianceStampedConstPtr& pose, const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& laserScan)
{
    m_localizerPoseWithScanCount++;
}

//Initialization
m_localizerPoseMsgFilterSubscriber = new message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::PoseWithCovarianceStamped>(m_nodeHandle, m_localizerPoseInputTopic, 5);
m_scanSubscriber = new message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::LaserScan>(m_nodeHandle, m_laserScanTopic, 50);

m_scanLocalizerPoseSynchronizer = new message_filters::TimeSynchronizer<geometry_msgs::PoseWithCovarianceStamped, sensor_msgs::LaserScan>(*m_localizerPoseMsgFilterSubscriber, *m_scanSubscriber, 10);
m_scanLocalizerPoseSynchronizer->registerCallback(boost::bind(&MyClass::localizerPoseWithScanCallback, this, _1, _2));
```

**Results:** I get 95 pairs for 203 poses, pretty bad, as expected.

#### Test2: Message filters, approximate time

That's the best candidate for now.

```
//Declarations
message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::LaserScan>* m_scanSubscriber;
message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::PoseWithCovarianceStamped>* m_localizerPoseMsgFilterSubscriber;
typedef message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<geometry_msgs::PoseWithCovarianceStamped, sensor_msgs::LaserScan> SyncScanWithLocalizerPose;
message_filters::Synchronizer<SyncScanWithLocalizerPose>* m_scanLocalizerPoseSynchronizer;

//Callbacks
void MyClass::localizerPoseCallback(const geometry_msgs::PoseWithCovarianceStampedConstPtr& pose)
{
    m_localizerPoseCount++;
}

void MyClass::localizerPoseWithScanCallback(const geometry_msgs::PoseWithCovarianceStampedConstPtr& pose, const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& laserScan)
{
    m_localizerPoseWithScanCount++;
}

//Initialization
m_localizerPoseMsgFilterSubscriber = new message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::PoseWithCovarianceStamped>(m_nodeHandle, m_localizerPoseInputTopic, 5);
m_scanSubscriber = new message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::LaserScan>(m_nodeHandle, m_laserScanTopic, 50);

m_scanLocalizerPoseSynchronizer = new message_filters::Synchronizer<SyncScanWithLocalizerPose>(SyncScanWithLocalizerPose(10), *m_localizerPoseMsgFilterSubscriber, *m_scanSubscriber);
m_scanLocalizerPoseSynchronizer->registerCallback(&MyClass::localizerPoseWithScanCallback, this);
```

**Results:** Unfortunately, the results are not better: 95 pairs for 204 poses.
Another run gave me 84 pairs for 194 total poses.

#### Test2: Tuning

I tried with AMCL tf_tolerance at 0 and at 0.1 (this is the default value), no difference.

I also tried to set the inter-message lower bound (parameter of ApproximateTime policy) to 0.02 (Half a period of laser scan)
and to set the maximum interval duration (parameter of ApproximateTime policy) to 0.15 (maximum allowable time difference between pose and scan ?), but no difference.

So far, the approximate time didn't gave me good results, so I am wondering what I am doing wrong ?
According to the documentation I would expect to not loose any pose message, and without doing too much parameter tuning.

Any thoughts ?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248677/how-to-synchronize-two-topics-without-message-loss-?/) by [Inounx](https://answers.ros.org/users/28459/inounx/) on ROS Answers with karma: 293 on 2016-11-23

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I do not know how to make this work to be honest, so I usually have a workaround.

I do it with a [message_filters::Cache](http://docs.ros.org/api/message_filters/html/c++/classmessage__filters_1_1Cache.html).

- Cache your `/scan`, if everything was smooth then a queue of (25/3) would be enough, but I would go for 100 messages at least.
- In your `/localizer_pose` callback, you can retrieve the latest message from the `/scan` cache with [`getLatestTime()`](http://docs.ros.org/api/message_filters/html/c++/classmessage__filters_1_1Cache.html#a33c0e7e177d5b355d7d67da853941784). You can also retrieve the latest message before a given timestamp.

---

Originally posted by [dotcom](https://answers.ros.org/users/19883/dotcom/) with karma: 120 on 2018-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Inounx](https://answers.ros.org/users/28459/inounx/) on 2018-07-04**:
Back then I worked around this problem by manually saving a laser scan and when receiving an AMCL pose, match with the last received scan. Didn't knew the option with the message filter cache, good to know.